# openstack using name instead of id

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

Can I use `name` instead of `id` for openstack api such as `show instance`? When I send `server name` in the url, I got `404`. Is there any way to get the `id` of the instance by means of its `name`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: It needs to be the ID.

According to the [API reference](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=show-server-details-detail,list-servers-detail#show-server-details), to get server details you `GET /servers/{server_id}`. And `server_id` is the ID, not the name.

The command `openstack server show` can be used with a UUID or the server's name. In the latter case, the command probably performs a `GET /servers/` [reference](https://docs.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/?expanded=show-server-details-detail,list-servers-detail#list-servers)) to convert the name to an ID, then the above `GET /servers/{server_id}`.

One way of learning about rules and best practices of OpenStack APIs is to run CLI commands with the `openstack --debug` option. This will show you details of the APIs that the command issues.